# tar.gz decompression with .ts results in different files in the browser?

Tags: javascript, typescript, compression, gzip, tar

I want a Typescript (or JS) gz extractor identical to command line. the issue is the decompressed file does not match the original. On the MacOS command line, it matches, but in javascript, even the size doesn't match.

I currently am using `tar -xzvf` on command line, for which the files decompress correctly to their original sizes in the terminal. Specifically, I use `tar_file.add(source_file_path, arcname=os.path.basename(source_file_path))` in Python to compress the file before I upload to s3.

In Javascript, I've tried a ton of different solutions. tar-stream and tar packages both result in files that are a bit too large (i.e. all files with original size under 10240 bytes become 10240 bytes). Pako is close but also doesn't do small files, and is like 50% off on one of the bigger files. Here is an [example file](https://s3://zkemail-zkey-chunks/email.zkeyd.tar.gz) on s3 that unzips differently in terminal and in JS.

Here is what works when I don't have a .tar.gz file; the binary file is totally fine:

```js
const store = async function (filename: string) {
  const link = "https://zkemail-zkey-chunks.s3.amazonaws.com/email.zkeyd";
  const resp = await fetch(link, {
    method: "GET",
  });
  const zkeyBuff = await resp.arrayBuffer(); 
  await localforage.setItem(filename, zkeyBuff);
}
```

Here is some example bad code when I do have a .tar.gz file:

```js
// Un-targz the arrayBuffer into the filename without the .tar.gz on the end
const uncompressAndStore = async function (filename: string) {
  const link = "https://zkemail-zkey-chunks.s3.amazonaws.com/email.zkeyd.tar.gz";
  const resp = await fetch(link, {
    method: "GET",
  });
  const zkeyBuff = await resp.arrayBuffer(); 
  
  console.log(`Started to uncompress ${filename}...!`);
  const extract = tar.extract() // create a tar extract stream
  const gunzip = zlib.createGunzip(zkeyBuff) // create a gunzip stream from the array buffer
  gunzip.pipe(extract) // pipe the gunzip stream into the tar extract stream

  // header is the tar header, stream is the content body (might be an empty stream), call next when you are done with this entry
  extract.on('entry', function(header: any, stream: any, next: Function) {
    // decompress the entry data
    const extractedData: any = []
    stream.on('data', function(chunk: any) {
      extractedData.push(chunk)
    })

    // make sure to call next when the entry is fully processed
    stream.on('end', function() {
      next()

      console.assert(filename.endsWith(zkeyExtension), `Filename doesn't end in ${zkeyExtension}`)
      const rawFilename = filename.replace(/.tar.gz$/, "");
      // save the extracted data to localForage
      localforage.setItem(rawFilename, extractedData, function(err: Error) {
        if (err) {
          console.error(`Couldn't extract data from ${filename}:` + err.message)
        } else {
          console.log('Saved extracted file to localForage')
        }
      })
    })
  })

  // all entries have been processed
  extract.on('finish', function() {
    console.log(`Finished extracting ${filename}`)
  })
}
```

And here is the code where I zip it up and upload it in Python:

```py
import boto3
import os
import tarfile

s3 = boto3.client('s3')  # Ask Aayush for the access key and secret access key

def upload_to_s3(filename, dir=""):
    with open(dir + filename, 'rb') as file:
        print("Starting upload...")
        s3.upload_fileobj(file, bucket_name, filename, ExtraArgs={
                          'ACL': 'public-read', 'ContentType': 'binary/octet-stream'})
        print("Done uploading!")


file = "..."
# Create a zip file for the file
tar_file_name = file + '.tar.gz'
with tarfile.open(tar_file_name, 'w:gz') as tar_file:
    source_file_path = dir + file
    print("Compressing: ", source_file_path)
    tar_file.add(source_file_path, arcname=os.path.basename(source_file_path))

# Upload the zip file to the AWS bucket, overwriting any existing file with the same name
upload_to_s3(tar_file_name)
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand, but is the issue that you are not getting the same file when decompressing compared to your original? Or is the issue that you're using 2 different methods to compress and you're not getting the *exact* tar.gz size?

Comment: Yes, the issue is the decompressed file does not match the original. In terminal, it matches, but in javascript, even the size doesn't match. I've edited the q to say this, good clarification.

Comment: What type of file is the source file? Is it a text file? can you see what's different between them (besides the size)

Comment: Also if it's binary. Where are you doing the measuring? After storing it in localStorage. I'm not sure if a binary file can survive going to localStorage and back.

Comment: When you say the size doesn't match, do you mean (**CASE #1**) the uncompressed file size does not match the size reported by "gunzip -l" or "tar tvf" ?  Or are you saying (**CASE #2**) the uncompressed file size on System A is different from the uncompressed file size on System B ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "in terminal". Do you mean "at the command line"? This sounds like it might be a sparse-file setting? The only other thing I can think of is the Character Map, UTF-8 vs 7-/8-bit ASCII. Just a thought.

Comment: It's a binary file @Evert. Why would it not survive? The uncompressed file size within the browser does not match the size reported by `tar -xvf`. Terminal = at the local command line.

Comment: @JohnTargaryen localStorage stores UTF-8 strings. If you decode a binary to an UTF-8 string you either 1) break the original, or 2) an error gets thrown. Any binary that needs to be preserved cannot be placed in anything that expects UTF-8 strings.

Comment: I use localforage -- does that do the same? @Evert

Comment: @JohnTargaryen do they use strings? Then you can't put a binary in there unless you base64 encode first.

Comment: localforage is just a unifying wrapper on top of localstorage and indexedDB. base64encoding first sounds promising, how would i go about modifying the above code to do so? I'll add the code where I get the files as well